# A DC++ client for Linux with user search

Tags: linux, search, sharing

As of now, the direct connect clients I know of on Linux are LinuxDC++ and EiskaltDC++, both of which do not offer search by user nickname. The DC++ client on Windows does so, though.

Is there a client for Linux as powerful as that for Windows?

Again, by powerful, I mean that it gives hub-wise user list, making it possible to browse through the user directory.

Answer (score 1):

- EiskaltDC++ Qt has a search by user nickname.
- EiskaltDC++ GTK and LinuxDC++ also has implicit search by user nickname: set mouse focus on userlist, and type the letters from a nickname (this implicit search has all software written on GTK).

Comment: How do I see the user list on LinuxDC++?